# Why did filmmakers choose to portray "What is Sodomy" in this manner?

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, everything-about-sex

The 1972 Woody Allen comedy, [*Everything You Always Wanted To Know About Sex (but were afraid to ask)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_You_Always_Wanted_to_Know_About_Sex*_(*But_Were_Afraid_to_Ask)_(film)) is a film divided into seven vignettes.

One of them is a parody titled "What is Sodomy?"  This features Dr. Ross (Gene Wilder) falling in love with a sheep.

While this scene is absolutely hilarious and shows the comedic brilliance of Gene Wilder..
**What did this scene have to do with sodomy?** 
The sheep in question is a female sheep named Daisy. **Is there any information given by filmmakers on why they chose to portray the skit in this way?**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44967/discussion-on-question-by-steelerfan-why-did-filmmakers-choose-to-portray-what).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> What did this scene have to do with sodomy?

[**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodomy) states that Sodomy includes Bestiality. The definition has altered in common language somewhat over time and locality.

> Sodomy (/ˈsɒdəmi/) is generally anal or oral sex between people or **sexual activity between a person and a non-human animal (bestiality)**, but it may also mean any non-procreative sexual activity.

---

> Is there any information given by filmmakers on why they chose to portray the skit in this way?

As for why Allen chose the *lesser known definition*..no information I can find...but it's seems the least...erm...controversial (I suppose) option of the choices available to them and thus the easiest to lampoon.

Comment: Really...it certainly answer the first part. I'm still looking for *why* the choice was made but I've addressed that too...partly.

Comment: Part of the question happens because Sodomy and Bestiality arn't considered the same thing anymore. The other part is, as Paulie explains, people screwing sheep is the funnier, dirty joke compared to consensual sex between two people.

Comment: Also, you forget the extra part of the joke. The sheep is one of the therapist's (Wilder) patient's partner. The Patient is Armenian, rural european. It's a "farmers screw sheep joke" as well.

Comment: The patient being Armenian is, I suspect, a placeholder, for country bumpkin...in the UK we'd use a Welshman instead.

Comment: Seriously, "sodomy" was pretty much a catch-all for anything not male into female genitalia, only.  If some had their way, probably non-missionary would be included, too.  As people have become more worldly/sophisticated/jaded, the terminology had become more clinically specific.